# How long is the delay before I can use TFS code search on my latest changes?

Tags: tfs, code-search

When I was trying to search through some the most latest checked in changes, I couldn't find them in the result set. The code search gives 22 founds only. While, I get a full set 38 founds using Notepad++ 'Find in Files'.

Then, I specifically searched the filename using TFS code search, which has the code I'm after.

It shows the file but with a note saying "You are viewing an older version of this file. Click on the filename link to open the latest version.". The searchable version doesn't have my latest changes, which do exist in the newer version of the file.
[image]

Do you know how long is the lag? Does is mean the code base needs to be re-indexed? Can we do it manually to make it search the latest code base?

Answer (score 0):

The delay is variable based on a number of factors, including CPU and disk speed of your search server, and the amount of code to be indexed.

Microsoft has some utilities available for [triggering reindexing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/search/code/administration#re-index) and checking indexing status available in a [public GitHub repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/Code-Search).